# Sql foreign key in grandchildren

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

I need help with the way we should structure our data. We are using MySQL. We have the following:

Area table:
One Area has many Locations

Location table:
One Location belongs to one Area
One Location has many Villas

Villa table:
One Villa belongs to one Location

So far so good. The thing is that we need to search for all the Villas in one Area (for all the Locations) . Someone, where I work, suggested adding the Area_id to the Villa Table. I have the feeling that is wrong since it might bring problems when we "update" a Villa, or what is called denormalization. I understand his suggestion makes it easier to search for the Villas in one Area, but I believe we are duplicating data.

The question is, how should we search for all the Villas in one Area? We are using Yii2 framework, therefore any suggestion on how to create the query within the framework is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicating data is almost always the wrong thing to do. In your case, all you need to do is join `Villa` to `Location` and `Location` to `Area`.